# Display actual time in a Qt program

Tags: qt, time, signals, slot

What is a simple way to display the actual time (Hh: mm: ss) in `MainWindow`'s title ?
Using slots and signals technology.

Answer (score 5):

I'm building my answer on [the one provided by Riateche](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579774/1951907). Instead of using a user defined `QTimer` and connecting signals/slots, you can use the provided `timerEvent()` of any `QObject`. It will basically do the same under the hood, but save you a lot of typing. This would look like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow();

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
     startTimer(1000);   // 1-second timer
}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent * event)
{
    setWindowTitle(QTime::currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"));
}
```

Comment: nice one, didn't know that event

Answer (score 3):

Create  a `QTimer` with 1 sec interval (or e.g. 100 msec for more accuracy), connect its `timeout` signal to your slot. In the slot get the current time using `QTime::currentTime()` static function, convert it to string using `toString` and assign it to a GUI element (e.g. a label).